# Exec shell command in symfony "No such file or directory"?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Using:

- Laravel 8
- PHP 8.0 (homebrew)

Problem:
Running any shell commands using Symfony: `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`

The following code executes on php7.4, but not on php8.0, both within Laravel 8

```
        $newDir = storage_path('test');
        $process1 = new Process(["mkdir ". $newDir]);
        $process1->run();

        if (! $process1->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process1);
        }
```

The result on PHP 7.4 is that the test directory is created within Laravels storage directory.

The result on PHP 8.0 is that the exception `ProcessFailedException` is triggered, with the result.

```
Error Output:
================
sh: /Users/username/code/project-name/mkdir /Users/username/code/project-name/storage/test: No such file or directory
sh: line 0: exec: /Users/username/code/project-name/mkdir /Users/username/code/project-name/storage/test: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I have attempted to use other commands and all give the same result

> cannot execute: No such file or directory

My suspicion is that it may be permissions related, but all related processes can be seen running as the user executing the process. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a full path i.e. `/bin/mkdir` and separate the arguments instead of `mkdir` plus string concatenation.

```
$process1 = new Process(["/bin/mkdir", "-p", $newDir]);
```

The `Process` component can't find an executable with name `mkdir [arguments]` in your current working directory.

Comment: Thanks, the relative directory did the trick. I can now work out how to run the other commands i need.